# how to hide main domain TITLE name from subdomain wordpress TITLE in google search

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WordPress in a subdomain, but when I google my subdomain. Show Subdomain TITLE - Main Domain TITLE. 
Please help me how to hide Main domain title from the search engine.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in the `header.php` file.

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<title><?php wp_title('&laquo;',true,'right');?></title>
```

It will remove the main domain name for the title.

Hope it will work for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, can i put it code to child theme or main theme.

Comment: You can also put it in child theme if you have

Comment: sir show this error.   Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 138 of file wp-content/themes/Kolyoum/header.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file. Screen shot this https://prnt.sc/kc1my3

Comment: Please put it carefully and check it.

Comment: By the way, you may have understood that I have to delete the title of the main domain.
Thank you, for guidance.

Comment: See the screenshot

Comment: Thank you sir It's okay now. I hope that maybe right now.

Comment: Sir, my problem was not solved, but the header had definitely disappeared. You can understand my problem here in the screen shot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms5JX.jpg

Comment: Okay, please see this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223325/how-can-i-remove-the-sitename-or-homepage-title-from-all-page-titles